# Реализовать метод, вычисляющий сумму цифр трехзначного числа

Tags: java

Написал программу, которая считывает введенное в консоль трехзначное число и вычисляет сумму его цифр.

Теперь надо ее расширить так, чтобы после результата пользователю задавался вопрос о том, хочет ли он продолжить работу, если он вводит "y", то программа опять просит ввести число, если "n", то программа завершает работу.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


/*
В переменной n хранится натуральное трёхзначное число.
Создайте программу, вычисляющую и выводящую на экран сумму цифр числа n.
*/
public class Exercise1 {

private BufferedReader reader;

public Exercise1(){
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}

public int read_hundreds() throws IOException{
    int value = 0;
    boolean isHundred = false;
    while(!isHundred){
        System.out.print("Введите трехзначное число: ");
        value = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if(value >= 100 && value <= 999) isHundred = true;
    }
    return value;
}

public void sumOfDigits() throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    char[] digits = String.valueOf(read_hundreds()).toCharArray();
    for (char digit: digits){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digit));
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of digits is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Начал только учить программирование, долго очень думал, не могу сообразить. Знаю, что надо использовать цикл while, пробовал разные способы, но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать цикл [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Допустим у нас есть буллевый метод, который спрашивает пользователя и возвращает true если пользователь ввел `y`:

```
boolean shouldRunAgain() {
    //спрашиваем пользователя
    String answer = //получаем ответ
    return "y".equals(answer);
}
```

То можно построить цикл так:

```
do {
     //делаем то что нужно
     sumOfDigits();
} while(shouldRunAgain()); //пока пользователь подтверждает
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать рекурсию, с последним else можно сделать красивее, но лень

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


/*
В переменной n хранится натуральное трёхзначное число.
Создайте программу, вычисляющую и выводящую на экран сумму цифр числа n.
*/
public class Exercise1 {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public Exercise1(){
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    public  int read_hundreds() throws IOException{
        int value = 0;
        boolean isHundred = false;
        while(!isHundred){
            System.out.print("Введите трехзначное число: ");
            value = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if(value >= 100 && value <= 999) isHundred = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void sumOfDigits() throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        char[] digits = String.valueOf(read_hundreds()).toCharArray();
        for (char digit: digits){
            sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digit));
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of digits is " + sum);
    }
    public void pup (Exercise1 exercise1) throws IOException {
        exercise1.sumOfDigits();
        String answer;
        System.out.println("продолжить?");
        answer =  reader.readLine();
        if (answer.equals("n"))
            System.exit(0);
        else if (answer.equals("y")){
            exercise1.pup(exercise1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("введите y или n");
            answer =  reader.readLine();
            if (answer.equals("n"))
                System.exit(0);
            else if (answer.equals("y")){
                exercise1.pup(exercise1);
            }
        }

    }
}

import java.io.IOException;

public class hg  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Exercise1 exercise1 = new Exercise1();
        exercise1.pup(exercise1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Плюс за обработку ошибок :) Рекурсия как правило применяется когда есть переход в другое состояние. Для повторения одного и того же действия писать рекурсию — не *comme il faut*. И да, самого себя (`exercise1`) в параметры передавать не нужно.